# Reatime with colume chart in Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I used highchart but i cannot custom barchart such as google chart realtime. How to draw chart as it. 
[Screen hot here](http://livenews.vn/res/chart.png)

Thank you very much.

Comment: you mean a drilldown chart? show a working example from where you took that pic..

Comment: It show in google analytics realtime

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific. What you have tried? What isn't working? Etc..  Take a look at this demo for a possible starting point: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update